# from PoseStamped message to tf StampedTransform

Tags: ros, transform-broadcaster, stampedtransform, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the neatest way to change a PoseStamped message into a StampedTransform to be published through a transform_broadcaster?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10323/from-posestamped-message-to-tf-stampedtransform/) by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at those:

```
name: tf::poseStampedTFToMsg
cmd: /^static inline void poseStampedTFToMsg(const Stamped<Pose>& bt, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped & msg)$/
namespace: tf
signature: (const Stamped<Pose>& bt, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped & msg)
filename: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h

name: tf::poseStampedMsgToTF
cmd: /^static inline void poseStampedMsgToTF(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped & msg, Stamped<Pose>& bt)$/
namespace: tf
signature: (const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped & msg, Stamped<Pose>& bt)
filename: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h
```

This is code I used a while ago for the inverse transformation:

```
  tf::Transform grasp_tf(gripperRotation, gripperOrigin);
  tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> grasp_tf_pose(grasp_tf);
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
  tf::poseStampedTFToMsg    (grasp_tf_pose, msg);
```

Edit:

I just needed to to that exact thing, so I mixed tf::poseStampedMsgToTF and tf::TransformStampedMsgToTF

```
namespace //anonymous
{ 
using namespace tf;
inline void myPoseMsgToTF(const geometry_msgs::Pose& msg, Transform& bt)
{
  bt = Transform(Quaternion(msg.orientation.x,
                            msg.orientation.y,
                            msg.orientation.z,
                            msg.orientation.w),
                 Vector3(msg.position.x, msg.position.y, msg.position.z));
}

///Sets the child frame fixed to "camera"
inline void myPoseStampedMsgToTF(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped & msg, StampedTransform& bt)
{
  myPoseMsgToTF(msg.pose, bt); 
  bt.stamp_ = msg.header.stamp;
  bt.frame_id_ = msg.header.frame_id;
  bt.child_frame_id_ = "camera";
  ROS_WARN_ONCE("You are using a path which does not carry the information about the "
                "name of the sensor frame. Using 'camera' as child_frame_id.\n"
                "Make sure the positions in your path are those of the 'camera' frame.");
}
}//anon namespace
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-04-12**:
I find these easy to use.

**Comment by [shamitb](https://answers.ros.org/users/25798/shamitb/) on 2016-03-07**:
Does this still work in ROS Indigo?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-03-09**:
I don't know. In Indigo you should probably use tf2 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your suggestion, I couldn't find a satisfactory way to change from tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> to tf::PoseStamped, and it was getting too confusing with bullet, so I just went for the easy, less-elegant:

```
tf::Transform transform_auxiliar;
transform_auxiliar.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose_msg.pose.position.x, pose_msg.pose.position.y, pose_msg.pose.position.z));
transform_auxiliar.setRotation(tf::Quaternion( pose_msg.pose.position.x, pose_msg.pose.orientation.y, pose_msg.pose.orientation.z, pose_msg.pose.orientation.w));

tf_br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform_auxiliar, ros::Time::now(), "openni_camera", "graspingPoint"));
```

Thanks, though.

---

Originally posted by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) with karma: 169 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-02**:
I think in line 3, for "tf::Quaternion", the first argument should be "orientation.x" instead of "position.x", right?